# Can't get an active vertical scrollbar

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, scrollbar

I've read a bunch of posts dealing with this issue but I can't get this to work under **my requirements**. There's probably some logical glitch in how I figure or I'm missing some crucial detail but I can't see it.

What I'm getting is a scroll bar but it seems to be inactive. My guess is that, because of the markup, the grid is rendered in its wholeness, making the scrolly feel unneeded. How can I make it feel otherwise?

I wish to create a window displaying a rather long data grid that is:

1. fixed in height
2. fitting the content in width
3. can't be resized

XAML

```
<Window ...
        SizeToContent="Width"
        Height="600"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
  <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button Content="Aaa" Click="Aaa_OnClick" />
      <Button Content="Bbb" Click="Bbb_OnClick" />
    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Things}"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"
                              Width="30"
                              Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                              Width="150"
                              Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

What do I miss?

Comment: not sure what you actually want, the third point ***can't be resized*** means it should have a fixed height and fixed width, so of course if the content size changes, it cannot change accordingly. Or do you mean the size can be changed but not via UI (by user)?

Comment: Exactly. I want the width to be fixed to whatever the children (the grid and its border) are "worth". And the height should be dead-locked to a fixed number. The user are not supposed to touch the sizing. I have that right now - the only problem is that the vertically scrolly is inactive (disabled, greyed out, unclickable).

Comment: You have a ScrollViewer on your window? When it comes to scrollbars, try using some attached properties in `ScrollViewer` class to change some behaviors.

Comment: @KingKing It was my understanding that the grid (or rather the window) has a scroll viewer by default and that it's the wisest approach to utilize that one. It's also implied by the scroll bar I'm getting on my screen, although it's inactive. When I turned of the fitting/fixing of the sizes, I even got the scroll bar to be activated and work. Right now, I'm a bit confused. If you have a suggestion on how to employ the scroll viewer control, feel free (in fact, feel urged) to post a sample as a reply.

Comment: do you mean DataGrid by `grid`? because the `Grid` control actually has no scrollviewer. If possible please add code you made to your window, I don't think the internal scrollviewer of DataGrid can be disabled for no reason easily.

Comment: @KingKing Yes, sloppy me. I meant data grid not grid-grid. Sorry. As for the code, I've posted it from the beginning. But I apparently forgot to indent it (sloppy me, again), so it doesn't show. I'll correct it right away. Take a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is you use a `StackPanel` to wrap your `DataGrid`. `StackPanel` will grow until it can contain the whole `DataGrid`, so in this case the `DataGrid` has its vertical scroll bar set to visible but in fact its height is expanded enough so that no scrollbar is needed to appear. If you set the scrollbar visibility to `Auto` instead, you'll see it never appears.

You should use a `Grid` layout instead, something like this:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
       <RowDefinition/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Button Content="Aaa" Click="Aaa_OnClick" />
     <Button Content="Bbb" Click="Bbb_OnClick" />
   </StackPanel>
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Things}"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1">     
       <!-- ... -->
   </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Or if you want to stick to the `StackPanel`, you need to wrap a ScrollViewer outside, like this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
   <StackPanel>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Button Content="Aaa" Click="Aaa_OnClick" />
       <Button Content="Bbb" Click="Bbb_OnClick" />
     </StackPanel>
     <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Things}"              
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
       <!-- ... -->        
     </DataGrid>
  </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Really good explanation. And +1 for examples on both approaches. I prefer not to use the grid layout (for some reason it seems stale when I have to specify row and column for the added children). I'll give a try with a *DockPanel* but if it doesn't work, I'll go with the external, wrapping *ScrollViewer*. Are there even more containers than stack, dock and grid?

Comment: @KonradViltersten besides stack, dock and grid, we have UniformGrid, WrapPanel, VirtualizingStackPanel, Canvas and some other special panels used in some controls including TabPanel, ToolbarOverflownPanel. You can even create your own custom panel (based on `Panel`). In fact the second code using a wrapper `ScrollViewer` should be fine as long as it's acceptable to scroll 2 Buttons along with the DataGrid. `DockPanel` should work well and don't require additional ScrollViewer. If you can use the DockPanel, it may be the best one you can use.